# jQuery: Transform forms to AJAX buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently writing a website. The bad thing is I wrote it with JavaScript in mind, so everything is AJAX based and the site doesn't work on browsers with JavaScript disabled.

Now I'm trying to change this by giving all links / buttons targets (href/action) and removing the onclick tags. Then I try to bring them back to what they where before that change with the help of JavaScript. Here's the code:

```
function transformLinksRecursive(from)
{
    var link
    var href;
    var tmp;
    from.children().each(function()
    {
        link = $(this);
        if(link.is('a'))
        {
            href = link.attr('href');
            if(!href || href.substring(0, 9) !== '/hashtag/')
                return;

            link.prop('id', 'menubutton_' + href.substring(9));
            link.click(function() { menuButtonClick(link.get(0)); });
            link.removeAttr('href');
            console.log("Link found: " + href + " / " + link.get(0));
        }
        else if(link.is('form'))
        {
            href = link.attr('action');
            if(!href || href.substring(0, 9) !== '/hashtag/')
                return;

            tmp = link.contents();
            link.replaceWith(tmp);
            tmp.prop('id', 'menubutton_' + href.substring(9));
            tmp.click(function() { menuButtonClick(tmp.get(0)); });
            console.log("Form found: " + href + " / " + tmp.get(0));
        }
        else
            transformLinksRecursive(link);
    });
}
```

The problem is that all buttons get the same target (tmp.get(0)). Let me explain some more:

the function menuButtonClick does this:

```
function menuButtonClick(parent)
{
    var link = parent.id;
    if(link)
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("_") + 1);
    else
        link = parent;

...
```

So it needs to read out the ID to get the link. The IDs are setted correctly:

[DOM tree of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGDHn.png)

But all and every button links to spinner (so parent.id always seems to be menubutton_spinner).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you make a study on your page and saw that most of your users use browsers with javascript disabled?

Comment: @madalinivascu No, the site is still in development but I showed it some friends and asked for opinions. What I heard most was "it's bad for NoScript users".

Comment: do some study , see how many users that you will want to have in your site will have js disabled and if this will have a major impact on your site

Comment: So I should just move the problem somewhere into the future and, when it's time for it, ask the very same question again? That doesn't sound like a good long-term plan.

Comment: the probability of someone having js disabled is small ,you are rewriting a good implementation because someone sad so

Comment: I just changed the codes slightly: http://pastebin.com/yAQQgBjB - These codes work like expected so my guess is the .each() calls are parallel and this is a race condition. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: buttons don't have links

Comment: Please re-read the codes. The buttons look like this (without JS) :

`<form method="POST" action="/hashtag/test"><input type="submit" value="Test" /></form>`

JS removes the form around the button (so it can't fire anymore) and adds an ID and a onclick event to the button.

Anyway, the codes are working now. All I need to mark this as solve is somebody to confirm it was a race condition caused by parallel code execution.